Import Realm issue - package path "." not exported from package */node_modules/realm
I want to use Realm to write to my MongoDB database through a website. I have tested my code with a standalone TypeScript file, which imports realm as follows:
let {Realm} = require('realm');
Now, I am trying to integrate this into my website, and have the following in my "db.ts" file
import Realm from 'realm';

interface MongoDBDocument {
    [key: string]: any;
}

export async function writeToMongoDB(document: MongoDBDocument, collectionName: string): Promise<any> {
    const app = new Realm.App({ id: <MY_ID> }); 
    const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
    try {
        const user = await app.logIn(credentials);
        const mongo = user.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas");
        const collection = mongo.db("txinfo").collection(collectionName);

        const res = await collection.insertOne(document);
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed:", err);
        throw err; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the calling function
    }
}

However, when I run pnpm build, I am getting the error:
Package path . is not exported from package <LOCAL_PATH>/node_modules/realm.  I am a newbie to all of this, but looking at *<LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/realm/package.json, I see the following in exports:
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/public-types/index.d.ts",
      "node": "./dist/platform/node/index.js",
      "react-native": "./index.react-native.js"
    },
    "./experimental/base-url": {
      "types": "./dist/public-types/experimental/base-url.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/experimental/base-url.js"
    },
    "./scripts/submit-analytics": "./scripts/submit-analytics.mjs",
    "./react-native.config.js": "./react-native.config.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },

It seems there is a "." exported.  Can someone please help me figure out how to import realm properly?  I have also tried import {Realm} from '@realm/react', but same error
My project's package.json looks like so:
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0",
    "realm": "^12.9.0",
    ...
  },


Do you have a realm field in your package.json?

Yes - I have the following in my project's package.json
"dependencies": {
...
"realm": "^12.9.0",
...
}

Updating the import to:
import * as Realm from "realm-web"; fixed the issue.
